# Avoid inline javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is essentially this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="viewServices(1)">Services</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="viewServices(43)">Services</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="viewServices(16)">Services</a>
...
```

Where viewServices:

```
function viewServices(stylistID){
    alert(stylistID);
}
```

Only, there are two problems:

1. I am using inline Javascript, and that is discouraged.
2. When I click a link, the function isn't called.

It should also be mentioned that I am importing JQuery and Bootstraps .js files, and that each link (as well as associated ID) is loaded dynamically.

**Is there an established method that will allow me to remove my inline javascript, but also make it so that I can call functions that pass the dynamically loaded link's "ID" to the function?**

** EDIT

Each link is generated during a mysqli_fetch_row that repeats until each row's information has been run through.  The number in viewServices(#) is actually

```
<?php echo $row[0]; ?>
```

Comment: why did you use `href="javascript:void(0);"` ?

Comment: I think `href="#"` would make it better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution is to utilize data attribute and class to refactor html like this

```
<a href="#" data-service="16" class="service-link">Services</a>
```

Then, jQuery

```
$('.service-link').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // Stop default behavior of clicking link
  alert(this.data('service')); // Retrieve the service id and use it
});
```

Comment: is `data-variable` new and a product of HTML5?

Comment: yeap... since HTML5 is not a REAL implementation of SGML, data-attributes are possible... once they couldn't be validated against a DTD.

Comment: @DanielBrown, yes data set is in HTML but actually not new :) It's widely accepted in almost all broswers. http://caniuse.com/dataset

Comment: 4 upvotes and no nones saw that `this.data(service)` should be `this.data('service')`...?

Comment: @plalx, I saw it and revised, same time as your comment :)

Comment: @BillChan, New to me then ;)  I really like your answer. If I understand right, the .on() is tied to the document, so any content loaded with the corresponding class and data element should trigger the event?

Comment: @BillyChan ;) It would also be better to use event delegation rather than adding a listener on every links.

Comment: @plalx, could you please expand on how one might use event delegation?

Comment: @DanielBrown, my pleasure :) `on()` listens to the events on the selector, no matter it exists or will be added later dynamically. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @plalx, would like to hear that too.

Comment: @DanielBrown, Sure `$('#links-container').on('click', '.service-link', ...);` This will take advantage of event bubbling, since click events are listened on the parent element. jQuery will automatically filter out click events that aren't coming from `.service-link` elements.

Comment: @plalx, Oh, okay. I think I get it. But to make sure that this works, I need to make sure that all of the links that could potentially call my function are in the `<div>` specified? And this should improve performance?

Comment: @DanielBrown Well, if you have links all over the place you can always listen for all clicks on the document: `$(document).on('click', ...)` However it's a good practice to reduce the scope as much as possible. You probably won't notice much difference, however it's more memory-efficient and could potentially increase performance. The most useful advantage is that you can add links dynamically without caring about adding new event handlers.

Comment: @plalx, I see you points. Yes, that's better on performance and management once the event divs are defined and fixed.

Comment: Thank you @plalx and BillyChan for your time and answers. I really appreciate the help! Learning stuff like this is what makes my day.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
<a class="viewServices" data-arg="1">Services</a>
<a class="viewServices" data-arg="43">Services</a>
<a class="viewServices" data-arg="16">Services</a>
```

and

```
// viewServices is not defined here
(function() { // viewServices is defined inside here
    function viewServices(arg) { /* ... */ }
    function viewServicesCaller() {
        viewServices(this.getAttribute('data-arg'));
    }
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName('viewServices');
    for(var i=els.length-1; i>=0; --i) {
        els[i].onclick = viewServicesCaller;
    }
})();
```

Probably, your code doesn't work because `viewServices` is defined inside a closure, so it isn't global. Then, you must add the event listeners in that closure.

Answer (score 1):

What errors are you getting in the console?

Is the javascript in the head section of your page? If not, try that.

If you don't want to do that, make sure the javascript code is before the link.

Good luck.

For jQuery, you could do this:

```
<a class="services" data-service="1">Services</a>
<a class="services" data-service="43">Services</a>
<a class="services" data-service="16">Services</a>


$(".services").click(function(link){
  link.preventDefault();
  alert(this.data("service-id"));
});
```